# Python - extracting key and value from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, object

I have a JSON tree similar to the following.

```
objArr = [{'plants': [{'inventory_id':1,'title':'Sunflower'},{'inventory_id': 2,'title':'Palm' }],{'plants': [{'inventory_id':1, 'title':'Succulent'},{'inventory_id':2, 'title':'Lillies'}]}
```

I am using python to iterate through the object array and return every array of objects underneath it. So far, I have accomplished printing the 'plants' with all of its corresponding values grouped in a single string. I have not however, accomplished the final step, which is to iterate through the individual 'plants' objects and extract their keys and values independently

The following is my intended output

```
singleObjArr = [{'title':'Sunflower'}, {'title':'Palm'}, {'title':'Succulent'}, {'title':'Lillies'}]
```

With a basic understanding of Python, I have put together the following script to extract the values.

```
objArr = [{'plants':[{'inventory_id':1,'title':'Sunflower'},{'inventory_id': 2,'title':'Palm' }],{'plants':[{'inventory_id':1, 'title':'Succulent'},{'inventory_id':2, 'title':'Lillies'}]}
for item in objArr:
    my_dict={}
    my_dict['plants']=item.get('title')
    print(my_dict)

# output: {'plants': None}{'plants': None}
```

I know I'm totally missing a step and I haven't figured out a way to get any closer after trying with different versions of that script, this is the closest I've come. Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Comment: Please do the last few lines of work to fill this out to a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Put your JSON input into a string and load *that*.  Correct your indentation.  *Then* someone will be able to help in a handful of minutes.

Comment: `[{'title': d['title']} for o in objArr for d in o['plants']]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a valid JSON, that is transformed into `objArr` as below, you can do:

```
objArr = [{'plants': [{'inventory_id': 1, 'title': 'Sunflower'}, {'inventory_id': 2, 'title': 'Palm'}]},
          {'plants': [{'inventory_id': 1, 'title': 'Succulent'}, {'inventory_id': 2, 'title': 'Lillies'}]}]

result = []
for item in objArr:
    for inventory in item['plants']:  # get the plants
        result.append({"title": inventory["title"]})  # for each plant grab the title 
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'title': 'Sunflower'}, {'title': 'Palm'}, {'title': 'Succulent'}, {'title': 'Lillies'}]
```

A more *pythonic* approach would be to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in combination with [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), as follows:

```
# plant extractor
plants = itemgetter('plants')

# title extractor
title = itemgetter('title')

result = [{"title": title(inventory)} for item in objArr for inventory in plants(item)]

print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I am getting the following error, which is consistent with my previous attempts `TypeError: string indices must be integers` when I use `["title"]`

Comment: Then the object you are doing ["title"] is a string